# How to layout grid items properly in a responsive site

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, grid

I am working on designing the layout a site which currently looks like this [Site snapshot](http://serwernr1.home.pl/akademiayogi.pl/stack/grid-items.JPG)

However, currently sub-elements on page have irregulars height. Can you please suggest any tutorial or approach for such problems?

**Using** Bootstrap framework and responsive design.

UPDATE:
I know that I can write it this way:

```
<div class="col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
    <div class="column col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
        <div class="element col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
        </div>
        <div class="element col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
        </div>
        <div class="element col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="column col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
        <div class="element col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
        </div>
        <div class="element col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
        </div>
        <div class="element col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="column col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
        <div class="element col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
        </div>
        <div class="element col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
        </div>
        <div class="element col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

But I don't know how to add elements to columns properly?

Should I measure hight of elements in JS and then append them to columns?

Comment: Why don't you use bootstrap too then? They have a good documentation

Comment: Something like Masonry will help you accomplish that layout, http://masonry.desandro.com/. @Pye Bootstrap won't help you with the Pinterest style of layout the OP is looking for.

Comment: I found this tutorial (http://tympanus.net/codrops/2013/07/02/loading-effects-for-grid-items-with-css-animations/) but when I am adding some text instead of images, it dosen't work good enaugh. (Items which should be under - coverd a little bit some text.

Comment: Thanks @hungerstar - I guess Masonry will help me;) I will post the result:)

Comment: masonry.desandro.com -> this is the thing which I was looking for. THANK You @hungerstar :)

Answer (score 0):

To have the same result just split the page un 3 divs of equal size and add others divs in these columns for the article.

Something like :

```
#column {
    width: 30℅;
    display: inline-block;
}

#article {
     width: 100℅;
}
```

Comment: While you could do this, the articles would more than likely not re-flow the way one would like. If the top three articles across are the most important, this solution fails. For example, we have three columns across and 10 articles in each column. The top right article would not be the third article from the top on smaller mobile devices or screens when all articles would be in a single column, it would be the 11th article in the column.